# How to find documentation in Core.Std?

Tags: ocaml

Where is the documentation for functions, symbols under Core.Std ?

Or, is there any **conventional** way to look up ocaml documentation rather than guessing in `utop` REPL ?

E.g. I know if `open Core.Std`, then the function `String.split` will be imported. But it's hard to find out what's the function parameter etc.

Also, Ocaml don't have source code links to it's documentation like Haskell does, I guess.

The current best solution is looking at: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core_kernel/#Core_string

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829625/on-finding-documentation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merlin](https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin) is able to perform documentation lookup and jump to the definition. In Emacs, I'm assuming, that you're using Emacs, the documentation lookup is not bound by default to any key, so I bound it to `C-c C-d`. Add the following to your emacs configuration file:

```
(define-key merlin-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d") 'merlin-document)
(define-key merlin-mode-map (kbd "C-c d") 'merlin-destruct)
```

The lookup function will jump directly to the `mli` file. This is my favorite way of reading the documentation. Unfortunately, due to a [bug](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/issues/51), Janestreet stopped to ship the `mli` file, so the feature is somewhat broken with the core. As a workaround, you can install source code with

```
opam source core_kernel
```

And then create a `.merlin` file, and point it to the sources:

```
S <path-to-sources>
```

Usually, it would be something like this

```
S ../core_kernel.113.33.00/src
```

Note, you should point merlin directly to the source subfolder.

It is also worth noting, that Merlin has intellisence like completion, that helps a lot, and you can hit `F1` when you choose an entry from a completion list, and a window with documentation will pop up.

And finally, the link to the documentation, that you're referencing is very outdated. Here is the link to the [latest documentation](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/).

Comment: If you're using vim, `:MerlinDocument` can do the same

Comment: @CodeFarmer Adding `PKG core` to `.merlin` (instead of `S <path-to-core_kernel-mli's>`) kind of solves the problem with getting docs. TLDR: `merlin-document` works for *fully-qualified* names. In Emacs: type `Core.Std.String.split`, hit `M-x`, then `merlin-document` will display the documentation. If I `open Core.Std` then `merlin-document` doesn't work for `String.split`.

Comment: `PKG core` should be there of course, but it is not enough for the lookup to work after version `113.33`, as the `mli` is not shipped anymore. This is just because, there is no `mli` to land in. So `S <path-to-source>` just gives an alternate place were merlin can land.

Comment: `opam list core`'s output: `core  113.33.02+4.03 ...`, it works without `mli`'s. Merlin v2.5.0 (OCaml 4.03). It seems merlin can extract the documentation from `.opam/<switch>/lib/core_kernel/core_string.cmti`.

Comment: @Anton, `merlin-document` works, I'm talking about `merlin-locate`. The former works, the latter does not. Yes, the docstrings are in the `cmti`.

Comment: If I add `S <path-to-sources>` to my `.merlin` file, `merlin-locate` jumps to the corresponding `ml` file (not `mli`).

Comment: That is controlled by the `merlin-locate-preference` variable. Set it to `'mli` and you will get the `'mli`.